# Ubuntu+1 Super-key not opening application overview on secondary keyboard layouts

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 20.04, beta

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 my super-key is no longer opening the activities overview when the keyboard layout is set to the secondary layout.

At first I thought it may have to do with the specific layout, but after switching the order of the layouts I use around the issue kept persisting only on the (new) secondary layout.

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: To prospective close voters: In less than a week this question will be on topic. I would suggest to abstain close voting, since the question may be useful to other users who stumble upon the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reported as [bug #1871913](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871913).